# Add attribute fileds on InventoryID Lookup on POLine

Tags: acumatica

I want to add Attributes on InventoryID lookup on POLine. I have written below code and in adding a column on InventoryId Lookup. I want to make the attribute field filterable. I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone please help me with this? And also I wanted to add the same filterable for InventoryId on ADD Item lookup on PO Screen.

```
            public class PXAddAtttributeColumns : CRAttributesFieldAttribute
              {
                string[] _names;

                public PXAddAtttributeColumns(string[] names, Type classID, 
                  Type noteID)
                   : base(classID, noteID)
                {
                       _names = names;
                }

        public override void CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
        {
            this._IsActive = true;
            base.CacheAttached(sender);
        }

        protected override void AttributeFieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldState state, string attributeName, int idx)
        {
            if (_names.Any(attributeName.Equals))
            {
                state.DisplayName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state.DisplayName)) ? (state.DisplayName.Replace("$Attributes$-", "")) : attributeName;
                state.Visible = true;
                state.Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Dynamic;
            }

            base.AttributeFieldSelecting(sender, e, state, attributeName, idx);
        }
    }

       public class InventoryItemExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItem>
       {

              public abstract class itemAttributes : IBqlField { }

               [InventoryItemMaint_Extension.PXAddAtttributeColumns(new[] { 
                                       "COLOR" },
                                        typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
                                        typeof(InventoryItem.noteID))]
               public virtual string[] ItemAttributes { get; set; }

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set FastFilterFields property for the POLine grid to make the attribute column filterable.

Example: FastFilterFields="COLOR_ItemAttributes"

This should allow you to filter the grid based on your attribute column in InventoryID lookup.